# ASP.NET MVC 4.6.1 BundleConfig.cs resources respond with 502 (Bad Gateway)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I started a new ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2017 and chose the MVC template and I've added a few angular scripts.

Here is my **BundleConfig.cs**

```
// Vendor CSS
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/vendorCSS").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap.css"));

// Vendor JS
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/vendorJS").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*",
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
    "~/Scripts/angular.js",
    "~/Scripts/AngularUI/ui-router.js"));

// App CSS
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/appCSS").Include(
    "~/Content/site.css"));

// App JS
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/appJS").Include(
    "~/app/app.module.js",
    "~/app/app.routes.js",
    "~/app/clients/clients.module.js",
    "~/app/clients/clients.controller.js"));
```

Here is how I render them in **_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>App Home</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/vendorCSS")
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/appCSS")
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-cloak>

    @RenderBody()
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/vendorJS")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/appJS")
</body>
</html>
```

If I add the line

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

to my `BundleConfig.cs`, then everything works as expected.

However, when I remove that I get the following error:

> **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)**

**Request URL:** http://localhost:62865/Content/bootstrap.css

I'd like to not have to minify everything when debugging.

**Web.config**

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
```

Comment: Show us your `app.config`. Do you have smth like `<compilation debug="true" />` there?

Comment: @ingvar yeah, I've added it to the question but <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>

Comment: Could you also show us the actual urls the browser is trying to load, that then fail with the 502 response?

Comment: @ChristophHerold - I added an example for bootstrap

Comment: That is very strange. I have not been able to reproduce similar behavior based on the steps you mentioned. Could you call the failing url in a new tab and see, if you can get some additional error information. IIS typically gives some detailed error codes in the markup, when you are doing local requests. Maybe that will help in finding out the issue.